# Creating the reverse of an association within a concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I have a concern that creates an association:

```
# concerns/product.rb
module Product
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :products, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: :owner_id
  end
end
```

And an example model:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Product
end
```

If I do: `User.products.last` it works fine. I also want to be able to do `Product.last.owner` but it won't work without the association being defined. I can't define it in the Product model since I have no clue to what models will include the concern that creates the association.

I have tried creating the association using inverse_of:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, inverse_of: :products
end
```

... but it won't work, apparently it needs a class name.

I've also tried reflecting on which classes the concern gets included within but it raises some strange errors when the concern gets included into several different models.

How do I create the inverse of an association from within the concern?

Comment: I thinks https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations is what you are looking for. In Product: belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true and has_many :products, as: :ownable in your Product module.

Comment: I have tried that, I don't want a polymorphic association because it forces me to have an additional _type column in my Product table. I just want to define the belongs_to from within the concern at inclusion time.

Comment: `belongs_to :owner` without polymorphism means this table has an `owner_id` column and the class associated with that association is only `Owner` you cannot have multiple classes. How would you know which class is associated with the product? How would the `User` instance know which products belong to it?

Comment: You can't use the exact same name for the module and class as that will cause a TypeError as soon as both are loaded into memory. Try `module Foo; end; class Foo; end` for an example of this. Find another name for the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @engineersmnky you can't actually setup an association that points to a bunch of different classes without using polymorphism:

```
# you can't have a class and a module with the same name in Ruby
# reopening the class/module will cause a TypeError
module ProductOwner
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_many :products, as: :owner
  end
end
```

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, 
    inverse_of: :products,
    polymorphic: true
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ProductOwner
end
```

The information about what you're actually joining has to be stored somewhere on the products table. If you don't use polymorphism you just have an integer (or UUID) which will always refer to a single table.

Comment: The only real expection to this if the User table is a Single Table Inheritince setup - but in that case your module doesn't even make sense as you would use classical inheritance instead of mixins.

Comment: So there's no way to add a belongs_to association to a class from another class (specifying the class_name and foreign_key)?

Comment: No, thats not what I'm saying. What I'm saying it that a standard `belongs_to` assocation just points to one other table - its just an id. Thats how it works. If you want to be able to to associate products to a bunch of different owner tables you need to store both the id and a type on products table. This really has nothing to do with your concern or the `has_many` side.

Comment: You can absolutely specify the `class_name`  - `self` inside the `included do ... end` block is the class that you're including the module in - and there also is a block argument that is the class `included do |klass| ... end` . You can specify the foreign key as well but that won't actually do you any good unless you plan on adding columns on the products table for every type of owner.

Comment: I'm going to accept this and use it for the time being so I can move on - thank you for the answer! I shouldn't have to add a "type" though since only one model gets extended and will have_many :products so there's no point in storing its class name, ideally I should be able to create the belongs_to association and specify the class_name based on whatever model includes the concern. Storing the type is redundant in this particular case.

Comment: Using a concern in that case mostly sounds like you're deceiving yourself and just making the code harder to maintain.

Comment: It's a part of a gem. The integrator may choose who the Products owner is by including the concern in their model.